# Какой уровень изоляции транзакций лучше всего выставить для CRUD операций?

Tags: java, база-данных, oracle, crud

Какой уровень изоляции транзакций лучше всего выставить для CRUD операций?
Oracle Database

Comment: Если сомневаетесь - поставьте read commited

Comment: @minotna  read commited по умолчанию. Явно можно вообще не ставить. И я даже не припомню ситуации, что бы в оракле этого было недостаточно. При условии выполнения commit в приложении действительно после выполнения логических транзакций, а не автоматом после каждой операции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев в Oracle достаточен уровень по умолчанию - READ_COMMITTED, насколько я помню, уровень READ_UNCOMMITED вообще отсутствует в этой базе. Иногда для специфических задач можно выставить уровень - SERIALIZABLE, это гарантировано закроет возможность фантомных чтений, хотя эту проблему вы можете проще решить на уровне своего приложения.